# FATAL Error in native method: Using JNIEnv in non-java thread

Tags: java, java-native-interface

I'm implementing some JNI callback (native -> java) functionality alongside another larger native framework and on one of the *framework's* callbacks I'm getting this error when trying to callback to *java*.

```
FATAL Error in native method: Using JNIEnv in non-java thread
```

What exactly does this mean? What is a java-thread and how do I go about using JNI in another native thread?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Java [must be attached](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/jni/spec/invocation.html#wp1060) to the thread on which it is to be executing.

> The JNI interface pointer (`JNIEnv`) is valid only in the current thread. Should another thread need to access the Java VM, it must first call AttachCurrentThread() to attach itself to the VM and obtain a JNI interface pointer. Once attached to the VM, a native thread works just like an ordinary Java thread running inside a native method.

To do this, you must store a pointer to the JVM object, either through the [`JNI_OnLoad()`](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-ndk/ceqeb6POkhQ) export or by storing it via a JNI `native` call you've implemented using `(JNIEnv*)java->GetJavaVm(&(JavaVM*)jvm);`.

From there, each time you need to use JNI, simply call the following in order to attach to the current thread and retrieve a new `JNIEnv*` pointer.

```
JNIEnv* AttachJava()
{
    JavaVMAttachArgs args = {JNI_VERSION_1_2, 0, 0};
    JNIEnv* java;
    jvm->AttachCurrentThread((void**) &java, &args);
    return java;
}
```

---

**Do not save instances of `JNIEnv*`** unless you are *sure* they will be referenced in the same thread.

As the [documentation states](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/jni/spec/invocation.html#attach_current_thread), calling `AttachCurrentThread` on an already attached thread is a no-op and thus is innocuous.